# SQL for matching input string on a given column that stores patterns

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

In Oracle db, I have a table let's say "test_table". This table has a column `"test_column"` that stores patterns like `^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]$`, `Batman*`, etc.

I have then an input in my Java app with value `"25"`.

What is the best way to find if my input string matches any row in my `test_table` ? Is there an easy query I can do or do I have to write `procedure` or get all **data** and **filter** in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `regexp_like()`:

```
select t.*
from test_table t
where regexp_like(:input, t.test_column);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried before this but it didn't work due to other issues that are now fixed. This is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, i.e.

> find if my input string matches any row in my test_table

then - wouldn't it be an ordinary

```
select * 
from test_table
where test_column = :input_value
```

That might need to be modified, depending on what "match" means to you. For example, this might be yet another option, which would check whether stored values *contain* input value:

```
select * 
from test_table
where instr(test_column, :input_value) > 0
```